# spring dependency maven multi module

Tags: spring, maven, maven-3

I Have below struture for my project:-

```
parent POM 
|-- app-core
|-- app-model
|-- app-services
`-- app-web
```

app-core : In **Springs**

app-services : In **jersey rest**

*app-services *uses* app-core.jar*

Question : If I add spring-dependencies to my app-core how does app-services can access the `applicationContext.xml`. Do I need to add spring-dependencies to my app-services module as well??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `app-core` as a maven dependency in the pom of `app-services` and you'll be able to access the `applicationContext.xml` as `classpath:applicationContext.xml`.